# Problem with auth in Firebase - why are my tokens instantly expiring?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm testing out a route in a firebase app I'm building. The route in question recieves 'shouts' which are akin to status updates. Anyway, I just integrated auth to protect this route using FBuath, but I keep getting the following error:

> Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again

I've tried relogging in using valid credentials, and then instantly trying to post something via the route, but keep getting this error. Any thoughts as to why? Code as follows, and the route in question has the endpoint '/shout'. Cheers

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

const config  = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBZjz9BNwj4UDwWLoQ1SOD5hB5QcNw3qqs",
  authDomain: "social-ape-21874.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://social-ape-21874.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "social-ape-21874",
  storageBucket: "social-ape-21874.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "323044904203",
  appId: "1:323044904203:web:edcbc619169a2087f8e60e",
  measurementId: "G-T34PXDM1X7"
}

admin.initializeApp

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const firebase = require('firebase')
firebase.initializeApp(config)

const db = admin.firestore()

app.get('/shouts', (req,res) => {
  db
  .collection('shouts')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc') //returns shouts in order in which they were made
  .get()
  .then((data) => {
    let shouts = []
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      shouts.push({
        shoutId: doc.id,
        body: doc.data().body,
        userHandle: doc.data().userHandle,
        createdAt: doc.data().createdAt
      })
    })
    return res.json(shouts)
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
})

const FBauth = (req,res,next) => {
  let idToken
  if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')){
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
  }else{
    console.error('No token found')
    return res.status(403).json({error: 'Unauthorized'})
  }
  //verify that this token was issued by our application
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(decodedToken => {
    req.user = decodedToken
    return db.collection('users')
    .where('userId', '==', req.user.uid)
    .limit(1) //limits results to one document
    .get()
  })
  .then(data => {
    req.user.handle = data.docs[0].data().handle  //data() is a function that extracts data from document
    return next() //next() is a function that allows request to proceed to shout post route
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error while verifying token', err)
    return res.status(403).json(err)
  })
}


app.post('/shout', FBauth, (req,res) => {
  const newShout = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle, //userhandle identifies who is owner of shout
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
  }

  db
  .collection('shouts')
  .add(newShout)
  .then((doc) => {
    res.json({message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully`})
  })
  .catch((err) =>{
    res.status(500).json({error: 'something went wrong'})
    console.error(err)
  })
})

//helper function to determine if string is empty or not
//note: .trim() removes whitespace from email field
const isEmpty = (string) => {
  if (string.trim()=== '') {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

//helper function to determine if valid email
const isEmail = (email) => {
  const regEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (email.match(regEx)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}


//Sign up route
app.post('/signup', (req,res) => {
  //here we need to extract form data from request body
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
  }

  let errors = {}

  if(isEmpty(newUser.email)){
    errors.email = 'Email must not be empty'
  } else if(!isEmail(newUser.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Must be a valid email address'
  } //if not empty, need to check if valid email

  if(isEmpty(newUser.password)){
    errors.password = 'Must not be empty'
  }

  if(newUser.password !== newUser.confirmPassword) {
    errors.confirmPassword = 'Passwords must match'
  }

  if(isEmpty(newUser.handle)){
    errors.handle = 'Must not be empty'
  }

  if(Object.keys(errors).length>0) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors)
  }

  //sign up user
  let token
  db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).get()
  .then((doc)=> {
    if(doc.exists){
      return res.status(400).json({handle: 'this handle is already taken'})
    } else {
      return firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    userId = data.user.uid
   return data.user.getIdToken()
  })
  .then(token => {
    token=token
    const userCredentials = {
      handle: newUser.handle,
      email: newUser.email,
      createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
      userId:userId
    }
    db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).set(userCredentials)
    return res.status(201).json({token})
  })
  .then(() => {
    return res.status(201).json({token})
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
    return res.status(500).json({error:err.code})
  })
})
//token is used to access route that is protected


//login route
app.post('/login', (req,res) => {
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  }

  let errors = {}

  if(isEmpty(user.email)){
    errors.email = 'Must not be empty'
  }
  if(isEmpty(user.password)){
    errors.password = 'Must not be empty'
  }

  if(Object.keys(errors).length >0) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors)
  }



  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
  .then(data => {
    return data.user.getIdToken()
  })
  .then(token => {
    return res.json({token})
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
    if(err.code ==="auth/wrong-password" ){
      return res.status(403).json({general: 'Wrong credentials, please try again'})
    } else
    return res.status(500).json({error: err.code})
  })
})


exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Comment: Is your clock in sync? ID token issue/expiry times are checked against the local clock.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka when I set my laptop time to the same time as the cloud firestore location, the problem was fixed. But I want people in any time zone to use my app without having expired tokens - any solutions on how to fix?

Comment: Usually your local clock only needs to be correct (in sync). The actual timezone doesn't matter as the JWT timestamps are expressed in number of seconds in UTC epoch.